# POST with JSON works in Postman but not in Python

Tags: python, json, post, urllib2, internal-server-error

Post with Json data is failing with python (both 2.7 or 3.6) throwing error "500 Internal server error" but works from Postman. Running python script from Windows 7 command prompt.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import urllib
import urllib2

url = 'http://<server>:<port>/web/services/notes2'
cont_type = 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36'
values = {
    "LK_IN_BRANCH": "00123",
    "LK_IN_ACCOUNT": "12345678",
    "LK_IN_ENTRY_DATE": "20190315",
    "LK_IN_ENTRY_TIME": "12300111",
    "LK_IN_HOLD_DATE": "20190331",
    "LK_IN_EMP_INITS": "QTC",
    "LK_IN_COMMENT": "Comment from py script-notes2",
    "LK_IN_USER_ID": "Hxxxxxxx",
    "LK_IN_NOTE_GROUP": " "}
headers = {
    "User-Agent": user_agent,
    "Content-Type": cont_type,
    "Accept": user_agent,
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate"}

try:
    data = urllib.urlencode(values)
    req = urllib2.Request(url, data, headers)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    json = response.read()
    print json
except urllib2.URLError as e:
    if hasattr(e, 'reason'):
        print 'We failed to reach a server.'
        print 'Reason: ', e.reason
    if hasattr(e, 'code'):
        print 'The server couldn\'t fulfill the request.'
        print 'Error code: ', e.code
```

If I add "Content-Length" SAME as Postman receive "400 Bad request" error.
[POST request/response in Postman Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgDP2.png)

POST request works using 'Requests' 3rd party package from my machine but unfortunately actual environment could not have 'Requests' installed so need it to work with standard builtin python modules. Also python script with builtin modules for GET works without any problems. I would appreciate any help with issue.

Answer (score 6):

You set the `Content-Type` header to `application/json` but sent the data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. This may be the reason for the HTTP 400 response.

Try to send your data as JSON string:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import json
import urllib2

url = 'http://httpbin.org/post'
cont_type = 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36'
values = {
    "LK_IN_BRANCH": "00123",
    "LK_IN_ACCOUNT": "12345678",
    "LK_IN_ENTRY_DATE": "20190315",
    "LK_IN_ENTRY_TIME": "12300111",
    "LK_IN_HOLD_DATE": "20190331",
    "LK_IN_EMP_INITS": "QTC",
    "LK_IN_COMMENT": "Comment from py script-notes2",
    "LK_IN_USER_ID": "Hxxxxxxx",
    "LK_IN_NOTE_GROUP": " ",
}
headers = {
    "User-Agent": user_agent,
    "Content-Type": cont_type,
    "Accept": user_agent,
}

try:
    data = json.dumps(values)
    req = urllib2.Request(url, data, headers)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    json = response.read()
    print json
except urllib2.URLError as e:
    if hasattr(e, 'reason'):
        print 'We failed to reach a server.'
        print 'Reason: ', e.reason
    if hasattr(e, 'code'):
        print 'The server couldn\'t fulfill the request.'
        print 'Error code: ', e.code
```

Comment: Indeed that was the problem, I figured out after posting here :) Anyways thanks for looking into it! I appreciate it!